# xcolor showing black with bookcover

Tags: color

I'm trying to define a background color for the delightful new `bookcover` package. The package relies on `xcolor`. However, even though I define a color that should be yellow, it seems to print black.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[coverwidth=130mm,coverheight=185mm,
  spinewidth=13mm,bleedwidth=5mm]{bookcover}
\definecolor[named]{yellow}{cmyk}{0,24,99,1}
\begin{document}
\begin{bookcover}
 %% Background Color
 \bookcovercomponent{color}{bg whole}{color=yellow}
 %    \bookcovercomponent{picture}{front}{v2gimp.jpg}
  %  \bookcovercomponent{picture}{back}{park.jpg}
 %%The class bookcover requires the services of the class article
 %%and    the following packages: kvoptions, geometry, graphicx, calc,
 %%xcolor, ifthen, tikz, eso-pic, textpos.
\end{bookcover}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Both of the below answers are correct. How do I select the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is not correct:
`\definecolor[named]{yellow}{cmyk}{0,24,99,1}`

Please read the document of xcolor package (page 10, Table3):

http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf

The parameters are between 0 and 1: cyan, magenta, yellow, black. If the last parameter is 1, then the color is black! Try the next one for example:

`\definecolor{amarillo}{cmyk}{0.4,0.1,0.1,0.1}`

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of the colour model - `cmyk` - requires the corresponding colour specification list to contain values between 0 and 1 (or fractions):

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  coverwidth  = 130mm,
  coverheight = 185mm,
  spinewidth  =  13mm,
  bleedwidth  =   5mm]{bookcover}

\definecolor[named]{yellow}{cmyk}{0,.24,.99,.01}

\begin{document}

\begin{bookcover}
  \bookcovercomponent{color}{bg whole}{color=yellow}
\end{bookcover}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the following error: "Package xcolor Error: Undefined color model `CMYK'.

Comment: I get the following error: "Package xcolor Error: Undefined color model `CMYK'. I tried adding \selectcolormodel{CMYK} and \selectcolormodel{cmyk} and neither compiled. I can't compile your MWE without getting the error.

Comment: If I change "cmyk" to "rgb" (with different values, of course) it compiles. Unfortunately I need cmyk output.

Comment: The error in your answer was you left my mistake in, you have to change the integers to percentages by adding decimal points. Now it works.

Comment: @user26732: I've updated the answer. I was confused with the `rgb` & `RGB` models provided by [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) which function in that way. See *Table 3: Supported color models* in the [`xcolor` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf), where it lists the parameter range for `cmyk` as being [0,1].